# Logrus escaping ampersand character

Tags: go, logging, stdout, logrus

I'm using Logrus and I have encountered an issue with displaying `&` character in its logs:

```
logger.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
        "value": "value&value",
}).Info("GET")
```

This prints `value\u0026value` i.e. hex value of `&` instead of `&` itself

Anyone knows how to fix this?

If it might be helpful, here's how the logger is being initialized:

```
    import (
       "log"

       "github.com/getsentry/sentry-go"
       sentry_hook "github.com/onrik/logrus/sentry"
       "github.com/pkg/errors"
       "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    )

    func newLogger() *logrus.Entry {
        log := logrus.StandardLogger()
    
        log.SetFormatter(&logrus.JSONFormatter{})
    
        level, err := logrus.ParseLevel(config.LogLevel)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("%+v", errors.WithStack(err))
        }
        log.SetLevel(level)
    
        hook := newSentryHook()
        log.AddHook(hook)
    
        entry := logrus.NewEntry(log)
    
        return entry
    }
    
    func newSentryHook() *sentry_hook.Hook {
        if err := sentry.Init(sentry.ClientOptions{Dsn: config.SentryDSN}); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("%+v", errors.WithStack(err))
        }
        hook, err := sentry_hook.NewHook(sentry_hook.Options{Dsn: config.SentryDSN}, logrus.PanicLevel, logrus.FatalLevel, logrus.ErrorLevel)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("%+v", errors.WithStack(err))
        }
        return hook
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This is the default behavior of the json package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder.SetEscapeHTML):

> The default behavior is to escape &, <, and > to \u0026, \u003c, and \u003e to avoid certain safety problems that can arise when embedding JSON in HTML.
>
> In non-HTML settings where the escaping interferes with the readability of the output, SetEscapeHTML(false) disables this behavior.

Logrus exposes this setting in the [JSONFormatter.DisableHTMLEscape field](https://godoc.org/github.com/sirupsen/logrus#JSONFormatter.DisableHTMLEscape).
To disable HTML escaping, set it to true:

```
log.SetFormatter(&logrus.JSONFormatter{
    DisableHTMLEscape: true,
})
```